# Derive $f(y, z)$ from $f(x, y)$ and $f(x, z)$

Tags: linear-algebra

Really I don't know if it is possible or not.
If I have $3$ vectors X, Y and Z where:

- $X = (x_1, x_2, x_3)$
- $Y = (y_1, y_2, y_3)$
- $Z = (z_1, z_2, z_3)$

And I have the following function:

$f(x, y) = x_1y_1 + x_2y_2 + x_3y_3$ -- let's name it $XY$

$f(x, z) = x_1z_1 + x_2z_2 + x_3z_3$ -- let's name it $XZ$

Can I derive the value of $f(y, z)$ from $XY$ and $XZ$ directly instead of loop on $Y$ and $Z$ vectors' elements to calculate it?

If it is not possible from the current function - sum multiplied pairs of value - so is there another function formula that can help to derive $YZ$ from $XY$ and $XZ$.

The objective is optimizing the processing time and derive the new combination from the existing ones.

Comment: Geometrically:  knowing, say, that X is orthogonal to Y and X is orthogonal to Z tells us very little about the relation between Y and Z.

Answer (score 2):

no, you cannot, for example 
$$
X=(1,0,0), Y=(0,1,0) \text{ and }Z=(0,0,1)
$$
then we get for $f(X,Y)=0$, for $f(X,Z)=0$ and how would you now like to deduce the value of $f(Y,Z)$ which is $0$ too?

Or check this example (thanks to Gerry Myerson), again $X=(1,0,0), Y=(0,1,0)$ but $Z=(0,t,1)$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ arbitrary but fixed, then 
$$
f(X,Y)=f(X,Z)=0 \text{ but } f(Y,Z)=t \text{ so the value only depends on the }Z \text{ vector }
$$
You have to calculate $f(Y,Z)$ on it's own as long you don't know more about the connection between the vectors $X,Y,Z.$ If the connection stays arbitrary, you have to calculate.

bests

Comment: Maybe a better example would be $(1,0,0)$, $(0,1,0)$, and $(0,t,1)$, where $f(x,y)=f(x,z)=0$ but $f(y,z)$ could be anything, depending on $t$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson right you are, I added your example to the answer